# Поиск числа с плавающей точкой в строке

Tags: c++, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>


double getVolume(double a, double b, double c) {
    return (a * b * c);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    char information[20][1000] =
    {
        " 25)Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 26) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 102.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 27) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 9) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 1) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 2) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 3) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 4) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 5) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 6) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 7) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 100.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 8) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 11) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 12) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 13)  Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 14) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 15) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 16) Стол цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 18) Шкаф цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см",
        " 19) Стул цвет – белый; ширина - 60.8 см; длина - 80.8 см; высота - 90 см"
    };
    int index = 0;
    double a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::string text = information[i];
        if (!(text.find("Шкаф") == std::string::npos)) {
            //std::cout << text.find("ширина") << std::endl;
            index = text.find("ширина") + 9; // возвращает индекс буквы "ш" в строке
            a = atof(&text[index]);
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
            //std::cout << text[index] << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Пытаюсь вытащить значение ширины из строк. Подскажите почему atof выводит целое число? Например 102, а не 102.8

Comment: видимо из-за ``setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");``, что делает разделителем запятую, а не точку